# String Value in a concat procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, concatenation

I know my questions sounds silly , but i'm not able to run my code because of that problem , all my procedure is correct , my only one problem is that i'm not able to use syntax that contains a string which is :

SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' WHERE i.active=T');

I tried to use  + between the apostrophe and . , however in all cases not working...

here is the full procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stocktakess()

            BEGIN
              DECLARE wid INT;
              DECLARE wname VARCHAR(20);
              DECLARE query TEXT DEFAULT '';
              DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
              DECLARE whouse_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, name FROM warehouse WHERE Id IN (1,2,3,5,8);
              DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
              OPEN whouse_cursor;
              SET @query = 'SELECT i.code,i.code2,i.description';
            get_whouse: LOOP
              FETCH whouse_cursor INTO wid, wname;
              IF finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE get_whouse;
              END IF;
              SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ', SUM(CASE WHEN m.warehouseID=', wid, ' THEN COALESCE(m.qtyin, 0) - COALESCE(m.qtyout, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS `', wname, '`');
              END LOOP get_whouse;
              SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' FROM items i LEFT JOIN itemmovement m ON m.itemid = i.Id');
              SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' WHERE i.active=T');  
              SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' GROUP BY i.Id');
              PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
              EXECUTE stmt;
              DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
            END
```

Comment: Umm `' WHERE i.active="T"'` ? or `' WHERE i.active=\'T\''`

Comment: @bato3 Good catch.

Comment: OR `' WHERE i.active=?'` and `SET @a = 'T'; EXECUTE stmt USING @a;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stocktakess()

            BEGIN
              DECLARE wid INT;
              DECLARE wname VARCHAR(20);
              DECLARE query TEXT DEFAULT '';
              DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
              DECLARE whouse_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, name FROM warehouse WHERE Id IN (1,2,3,5,8);
              DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
              OPEN whouse_cursor;
              SET @query = 'SELECT i.code,i.code2,i.description';
            get_whouse: LOOP
              FETCH whouse_cursor INTO wid, wname;
              IF finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE get_whouse;
              END IF;
              SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ', SUM(CASE WHEN m.warehouseID=', wid, ' THEN COALESCE(m.qtyin, 0) - COALESCE(m.qtyout, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS `', wname, '`');
              END LOOP get_whouse;
              SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' FROM items i LEFT JOIN itemmovement m ON m.itemid = i.Id');
              SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' WHERE i.active=\'T\'');  
              SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' GROUP BY i.Id');
              PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
              EXECUTE stmt;
              DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
            END
```